# Setting to download app updates only when connected to power?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

The last 3 days the app using the most power according to my iPhone is the App Store. I'm guessing it's downloading app updates. Is there a setting to only download updates while the phone is charging?

Comment: low power mode should work

Answer (score 3):

Yes.   Turn on low power mode.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205234

Comment: Hmmm, I don't really want the merf the entire phone experience just to turn off app downloading 

Comment: I honestly can’t tell when it’s on, so there not much “merf” -  if you don’t like that, I suppose turn off automatic updates. Those are the only two levers you have afaik